# HLS files(.m3u8, .ts) not generated with pull on RTMP stream

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I setup nginx to stream rtmp and I am able to stream to it perfectly and play it at rtmp://[insterip]:1935/stream/test with VLC.

I tried using ffmpeg to transcode and it started to populate /mnt/hls with the proper files. I wanted to avoid transcoding on this server since it's older so I was attempting to use the pull function to just pull it straight from the rtmp stream.

I'm using OBS to stream to the server which by default should use the proper codec for video and audio for hls to use. Keep in mind I played with the pull url putting the IP in as it's supposed to be and the ports are allowed through the firewall as I was able to hit the stream with a secondary pc on the network. This is all configured in Centos 8.

nginx config

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

# Define the Application
        application show {
            live on;
            pull rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/test;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }

        # RTMP video on demand for mp4 files
        application vod {
            play /mnt/mp4s;
        }

        # RTMP stream using OBS
        application stream {
            live on;
        }

    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    aio on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /mnt/;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the "static" option as such:

```
pull rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/test static;
```